# 'so far' with simple past tense?

Tags: tense, phrase-usage

I am confused with the use of 'so far' wirh simple past tense in the following question. Please explain it to me.

> What was the best part of your day, so far?

Comment: "So far" means "until now".

Comment: @Old Brixtonian. Shouldn't the question be like 'what is/has been the best part of your day so far?'.

Comment: Yes! (I edited my comment to say that, but then I ran out of editing-time!) "What has been the best part of your day so far" is perfect. "What did you do yesterday?" "What have you done today?" "I was in bed all day yesterday." "I have been in bed all day today".